# Reading and understanding data from RJ45

Tags: macos, data-transfer, rj-45

Situation... I have a solar setup that power up a few secondary utilities here at home. It's a simple setup that I hooked up a monitor that display a few stats for the system. that monitor is connected to the charge controller and inverter using some RJ45 (two out of the monitor, one to the charge controller and another to the inverter).

Question... How can I plug that RJ45 on my Mac Pro and read the data ( and mostly important, understand the data) so I can collect the info and report on it locally?

The brand has an online service that I can hook up some WIFI dongle and see the stats online but never managed to make it work as there is a sign up with this Chinese company and the sign up doesn't work and contact is non existent.

TIA

Comment: Why the downvote? Such a sucker move without an explanation... How could I improve the question if I don't know the problem?

Comment: Perhaps lack of documented effort on your behalf (I didn't downvote). So you asking something somewhat as if there's a simple answer that some one could give in a few paragraphs, while in reality this is a research project in itself may tick off someone.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but first it shows a lack of research, and second it isn't really about a personal computer, hardware or software. You'll need to know the protocol being used on this cable. Rj45 is a common and inexpensive cable and connector, and easily used for things other than network.

Comment: @Desorder These questions can really only be answered based on documentation from the device's manufacturer. Without even knowing the manufacturer (let alone model number), it's impossible to do more than speculate. *With* the manufacturer and model number, it'll depend on what info they publish (and/or any reverse engineering anyone's done).

Answer (score 3):

That really depends on whether the RJ-45 port is actually used for Ethernet traffic. When you connect it to your computer does the link led turn on? If it's indeed standard Ethernet then you can use Wireshark to capture everything that goes over the wire. Whether that's understandable or not is anyone's guess. There's no guarantee that you will be able to understand it (e.g., if the protocol is encrypted there's no way to understand it unless you reverse-engineer the device...)

The other possibility is that it might be an RJ-45 plug but it's not Ethernet traffic at all. After all a CAT cable is just 4 twisted pairs, so it can be used for virtually anything. One of the offices I used to work at used them for landline phones (since they had no RJ-11 sockets), completely analog. If that's indeed the case and the RJ-45 plug is only used as a convenient wire then unfortunately there's no way a computer's Ethernet connection could get any data off of it. Furthermore it would be dangerous to even connect it to any networking equipment since wires may have relatively high voltage which could damage your computer.

Comment: Yeah. You touched some of my concerns here. I didn't want to plug in and cook one of my devices as I wasn't sure what's happening there. The other thing you raised that I was hoping to get an answer was that, a RJ45 is just some copper wire and anything could be happening there. I've done something similar about 20y ago but I had more info about the device back them so was more hoping things had improved and it there was something out there that I could use more readily available. I'm not too fussy about online monitoring really as that solar setup tends to just work.